# List "sys.argv" empty after import sys

Tags: python, list, sys

I have a script with the following imports:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


sc = sys.argv[1]
run = sys.argv[2]

...
```

when I run it it kicks back the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/brandonsmith/climate-sensitivity-gcm/plot_scripts/map_lowcloud.py", line 11, in <module>
    sc = sys.argv[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

so I checked the list contents and it came up empty:

```
In [28]: sys.argv
Out[28]: ['']
```

Why?

Comment: What were the arguments you gave the program when you ran it?

Comment: @GreenMatt I'm not sure what you mean, did I misuse the sys import somehow?

Comment: @Brandon `sys.argv` is used to refer to command-line arguments. In the command `python myfile.py test`, `sys.argv[1]` refers to the string `test`

Comment: @JammyDodger so will the script work if I remove the sys.argv commands?

Comment: Does any of your code depend on `sc` or `run`? If you got this code from somewhere else, have you looked up how it should be run?

Comment: @JammyDodger both variables are referenced in the script, mainly for the purpose of creating paths for the outfiles produced by the script. This program and others were passed down by graduate students at a university who have since graduated, and left behind unfinished projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a program from a command line prompt it receives arguments from the command line program (a shell program such as bash in *nix, the cmd prompt in Windows). An example will probably help:

```
> python my_program Brandon GreenMatt
```

In this case, you are telling the command line program to run python. The arguments you are giving to python are "my_program", "Brandon", and "GreenMatt". In turn, python tries to find and run a program named "my_program", which will receive the arguments "Brandon" and "GreenMatt".

Python's mechanism for handling arguments is sys.argv. The first argument - numbered 0, i.e. sys.argv[0] - will be the program name. Other arguments will be loaded into sys.argv in the order they appear on the command line. Thus in the example I gave above, my_program will see "Brandon" in  sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2] will hold "GreenMatt".

When there are no arguments on the command line, e.g.:

```
> python my_program
```

then sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2] will not have anything in them, resulting in the error you see. Also, if you load the program into some sort of Python interactive environment and just run it you will see this error.

More in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

Comment: That must be my problem then, because I'm running this program in Spyder. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Brandon: It has been a while since I've used Spyder, but I think it has a means of specifying arguments to be passed to the program.

Comment: @Brandon: My system has an old version (3.7) of Spyder, but in it I was able to set command line options via Ctrl+F6 (or Run | Configuration per file), then checking the "Command line options" box and entering the values into the corresponding text box.

Comment: That fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is using a Python Interactive Environment (i.e. Spyder, Jupyter), you'll need to specify command line options. I am using Spyder, so this can be accomplished by finding the "configurations  per file" button under the "run tab", then selecting "command line options" and entering what would come after the run command. Thanks goes to person who posted the accepted answer.